# get substrings ignoring characters with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

My problem is the following, I want to find all the occurrences of a substring in a string. More specifically I want to find all sets of indices `s[0]...s[n]` so that if `st` is the string `st[s[0]], st[s[1], ... st[s[n]]` matches the sought substring. "BUT WHY??" you ask, well... because it's up here [on code jam](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/90101/dashboard#s=p2). It's pretty easy to solve by doing sequential comparison of all possible permutations, but it gets slow for large strings. So I thought regexes.

As an example, for the string 'abcoeubc' and the substring 'abc' it should give me the indices [(0,1,2),(0,1,7),(0,6,7)], or something of the like. I don't really want the indices, but just to count the number of suboccurrences. I've been trying something like

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'a.*b.*c')
matches = [m for i in r.finditer('abcoeubc')]
```

but it doesn't really behave as I expected. I've tried it with lookahead expressions too, with something like `r = re.compile(r'(?=a).*(?=b).*(?=c)')` but that don't work either. Am I wrong to try to use regexes for that?

Comment: Actually there is a much simpler way to solve this problem which is storing a list of indices that match each individual character in the entire string and doing iterative combinations of just those indices such that s[0] < s[1] etc. That's a lot more efficient than naively taking all permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

#### Sub-Edit:added some juicy low-hanging fruit. Slightly more obscure, measurably faster.

You want speed?

*Super* speed?

Well...

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def count_ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i, max=float("inf")):
    last = sequence_indexes[i]
    end = bisect_right(last, max)

    return sum(
        count_ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i-1, item)
        for item in last[:end]
    ) if i else end

def count_allpaths(target, sequence):
    sequence_chars = {k: [] for k in sequence}
    for i, character in enumerate(target):
        if character in sequence_chars:
            sequence_chars[character].append(i)

    sequence_indexes = [sequence_chars[character] for character in sequence]

    return count_ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, len(sequence_indexes)-1)
```

---

---

You *cannot* do this with Regex because Regex does not look to find all possible matches, only show that positions match the Regex you're searching with.

Here's a solution, I'll update with explanations:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i, max=float("inf")):
    last = takewhile(lambda item: item < max, sequence_indexes[i])

    if i == 0:
        for item in last:
            yield [item]

    for item in last:
        for subitems in ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i-1, item):
            subitems.append(item)
            yield subitems

def allpaths(target, sequence):
    sequence_indexes = []
    for character in sequence:
        sequence_indexes.append([i for i, c in enumerate(target) if c == character])

    return ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, len(sequence_indexes)-1)

list(allpaths("abcoeubcbc", "abc"))
#>>> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 7], [0, 6, 7], [0, 1, 9], [0, 6, 9], [0, 8, 9]]
```

---

Enough edits, onto the explanation!

If you have the characters `abcoeubcbc` and you want to characters `abc` in order from it, you're looking at

```
0123456780
abcoeubcbc
----------
abc       
ab     c  
a     bc  
ab       c
a       bc
```

Instead of reading it forwards, which is the obvious interpretation, read it *backwards*.

Look at where the `c` is in each of those. It's in position 2, 7 and 0 in turn.

When it's in position 0 you can ignore everything after it because those would be out-of-order:

```
012
abc
---
abc
```

And do the same for `b`. Well, it only has one position, and the same for `a`, so that's easy. On to the next part:

```
01234567
abcoeubc
--------
ab     c
a     bc
```

The `b` can go in two places. In both cases `a` has one slot.

Then for the final position:

```
0123456780
abcoeubcbc
----------
ab       c
a       bc
```

Once again `b` has two positions, and then we recurse for each and `a` only has one position.

More about how this relates to the code below after I sate my deep hunger!

---

And I'm back, a bit later than I expected. No rush, I guess, as OP doesn't even seem to have noticed me...

First we should look at `allpaths`.

```
def allpaths(target, sequence):
    sequence_indexes = []
    for character in sequence:
        sequence_indexes.append([i for i, c in enumerate(target) if c == character])

    return ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, len(sequence_indexes)-1)
```

`allpaths` is a **wrapper function** — it doesn't actually implement much, other than setting up conditions for `ascending_permutations`. This is needed because, as you'll see later, `ascending_permutations` is recursive and we only want to run this part once.

Firstly,

```
for character in sequence:
    sequence_indexes.append([i for i, c in enumerate(target) if c == character])
```

generates for each character the index of every occurence in the word. This is a "matrix" in the sense that it's a list of lists:

```
  abcoeubcbc
  ----------
a|0         |  →  [[0,     ],
b| 1    6 8 |  →   [1, 6, 8],
c|  2    7 9|  →   [2, 7, 9]]
  ----------
```

The current method takes `O(len(target) × len(sequence))`, this could be optimised to `O(len(target) + len(sequence))` by using a dictionary:

```
sequence_chars = {k: [] for k in sequence}
for i, character in enumerate(target):
    if character in sequence_chars:
        sequence_chars[character].append(i)

sequence_indexes = [sequence_chars[character] for character in sequence]
```

That's cool, methinks.

Then it sends this matrix to `ascending_permutations`, which does the actual work.

`ascending_permutations` works backwards from the end of the list. This might sound odd, but it's a well-founded construct.

Say you have the recursive algorithm for factorial:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n

    return n * fact(n-1)
```

Calling `fact(3)` does `fib(3) == 3 * fib(2) == 3 * (2 * fib(1)) == 3 * (2 * (1))` and we can see that we work outwards from the `1 → 2 → 3` when multiplying, because of the brackets. Because we want to use `append` to build our list (it's fast to `append`, slow to `insert(0, item)`) we want to do:

```
(((our_list).append(a's position)).append(b's position)).append(c's position)
```

and so we can see that the outermost scope is `c`, not `a`. Therefor we should start with `a`.

We also pass `len(sequence_indexes)-1` to `ascending_permutations` because we don't want to keep on `pop`ing items and pushing them back on; we're going to be recursing in and out and it's much easier to keep track of where we think the "end" is. `len(sequence_indexes)-1` is the position of the last item in `sequence_indexes`, which is the lot of indexes for `c` in this case.

So, now on to the meat of the function...

---

```
def ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i, max=float("inf")):
```

`max` keeps track of a different kind of end; wheres `i` keeps track of the letter, `max` keeps track of the highest index to search to:

```
     max→

     abcoeubcbc
     ----------
i  a|0         |  →  [[0,     ],
↓  b| 1    6 8 |  →   [1, 6, 8],
   c|  2    7 9|  →   [2, 7, 9]]
     ----------
```

We then want to iterate through our "active" letter, which is the last one:

```
    last = takewhile(lambda item: item < max, sequence_indexes[i])
```

Note that we use `takewhile` to crop the number to `max`, so no indexes go past, or up to, the letter that we calculated previously. `max` starts as infinity, so there's no limit before you've chosen a letter!

We then have an end-condition:

```
    if i == 0:
        for item in last:
            yield [item]
```

Basically this says that if you have only one letter, your "paths" are just the indexes of the letter.

Finally we're at the heart of the recursion.

For every index that our letter is on, we need to recurse individually. For `c`, we recurse into indexes `2`, `7` and `9`, for example.

```
    for item in last:
```

Then we need to get all the paths for our "cropped" amount.

```
        for subitems in ascending_permutations(sequence_indexes, i-1, item):
```

Remember this:

```
01234567
abcoeubc
--------
ab     c
a     bc
```

? That's what the recursion did: it took the subset where a particular position for `c` is given (in this case `7`) and reduced the problem to just that part.

Now we have our list for that sub-section, we can add our position (in this example `7`, remember) to the end and throw the result "upstream".

```
            subitems.append(item)
            yield subitems
```

---

## That's it. Simple, eh?

Comment: Wow, man, how's that for an extensive reply! Sadly I only get one upvote. This is approximately how I implemented it, without itertools because I only wanted the count, so I just counted the valid occurrences. I'll post it as an alternative answer, but yours seems to do the trick and great explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I solved it without regexes, but it gets really slow for large inputs. I'll try and check the alternative implementation...

```
import re
def simple_match( string, pattern ):
    count = 0
    # if there's only one character left, return the number of occurrences
    if len(pattern)==1:
        return len(re.findall( pattern, string ) )
    # otherwise find all occurrences of the first char of the remaining string
    pos = [i.start() for i in re.finditer( pattern[0], string )]
    # and for each position
    for i in pos:
        # check if the next char still comes up in the remaining string
        next2 = re.search( pattern[1], string[i:])
        # if it doesn't it, there are no valid substrings remaining, so break
        if next2 is None:
            break
        # else recur with the remaining string and pattern
        count+=simple_match( string[(i+1):], pattern[1:] )
    return count
```

Might be less efficient, don't really see why though.

Comment: Yours is likely slower for exceptionally large strings (10k or more characters) because you search the whole string each iteration through. It has a lower constant factor, though, so it's faster for shorter things. I'll see if I can improve mine in that regard. // Note that I didn't realise you were *counting* these, I enumerated them and there should be some shortcuts that let me speed things up...

Comment: What about now? Mine should be plenty fast!